# Rich UI in ASP .net applications

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I am trying to explore the options that are available for developing rich and smooth UI in ASP .net applications. Things of interest are page loading spinning bar, progress indicator, expanders, popups, charts etc., May I know if there are any open source components that are available. As of now I have infragistics control, but not fully utilized. Any help or references would be appreciated.

Comment: Of course silverlight as well. Do you recommend ASP .net with silverlight as well since its an intranet based applicaton

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend JQuery for your UI needs.  There are so many plugins available as well.